# How do I get rid of the big margin between my labels and the input fields?

Tags: html, css

Below is my code, first of all:

- How do I get rid of the big margin to the right that occurs between the labels and the input fields? I tried setting the `margin-right` to `-150px` which made it smaller but that just seems like an idiotic solution..
- How can I remove the need to write `<br />` to make them hop down a line automatically? I was told never to use `<br />`, it also seems messy.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="groupmepopup" class="popup">
<h4>Fill in your information so that you can be added.</h4>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <label>In-game username:</label>
                    <input name="username" type="text"></input><br />
                <label>Email:</label>
                    <input name="email" type="text"></input><br />
                <label>Game:</label>
                    <input name="game" type="text"></input><br />

            <input name="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
            </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
<div id="groupmepopup" class="popup">
<h4>Fill in your information so that you can be added.</h4>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <p>
      <label>In-game username:</label>
      <input name="username" type="text"></input>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Email:</label>
      <input name="email" type="text"></input>
    </p>
    <p>
     <label>Game:</label>
     <input name="game" type="text"></input>
    </p>
    <p></p>
    <input name="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
 </form>
</div>
```

and then the css

```
p label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

p input{
    float:right;

}

p{
clear:both;
}

form{
    width:20em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V92PT/1/

Comment: that just makes everything have its own line and it jumps out of the containing div which is only 450px wide and 170px high.

Comment: Then you can change the width on the form. I was only using that as an example, look at my fiddle above.

Comment: I changed it to 400px, that fixed it, but, there is still a big margin between the label and the input field, and the submit button comes between the last label and the input field.

Comment: if you put `text-align: right` in your fiddle you can see what my problem is.

Comment: The margin is now being controlled by the width of your form. If you reduce the width of the form then the margin will shrink.

Comment: The issue is that text-align right, that was why I left it out.

Comment: reducing width does help, but I need the text-align: right for it to look better and it doesn't seem to be causing the problem.

Comment: The text-aligh:right; is causing the issue. If you take it out you will see the margin does disappear. That style is telling it to lign up all the elements to the right side thus creating a space, if you would like to remove that space and align it to the left then you either need to take the style out or change it to text-align:left;

Answer (score -1):

But the fields part on table
like this

```
<div id="groupmepopup" class="popup">
<h4>Fill in your information so that you can be added.</h4>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <table><tr><td><label>In-game username:</label></td>
                   <td> <input name="username" type="text"></input></td ></tr>
                    <tr><td>   <label>Email:</label></td>
                        <td>  <input name="email" type="text"></input></td></tr>
               <tr><td>  <label>Game:</label></td>
                        <td> 
                    <input name="game" type="text"></input>
</td></tr>
                </table>
            <input name="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
            </form>
</div>
```

or add another `<br/>` after `<label>In-game username:</label>`

or use `<p></P>` for each row